# Windows 7 freezes on 'Starting Windows' screen after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Win7. I have done exactly this before, but my hard drive had to be replaced (unrelated reasons) and I had to start again.

Install went through smoothly, I rebooted the system, and 2 entries for Win7 came up in GRUB(alongside the usual ubuntu ones). For some reason, it detected the recovery partition (100 odd mb) as a separate Win7 OS. This had not happened last time.

When I press enter on either of these Win7 entries, the splash screen comes up but freezes on 'Starting Windows'.

Ubuntu boots fine.

Running 'bootrec /fixmbr' from the Win7 DVD fixes the MBR and Win7 boots fine after that, suggesting no corruption on Win7.

Something GRUB is doing is preventing Windows from booting properly.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First, try running Boot-Repair(info) and see if this helps. To run this:

Boot from a Ubuntu live CD or USB

Type these lines in the terminal one line at a time.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Search for Boot-Repair in the Dash and launch it.[image]
To fix your computer with Boot-repair, simply click the "Recommended Repair" button. If it worked, you are done.

If Boot Repair didn't work, run a repair with a Windows Recovery CD (ask for one from your PC manufacturer).

1. Boot from a recovery CD. You should see this. 
   [image]
2. Open the Command Prompt and type bootrec /fixmbr. 
   [image]
   3.Close the Window and choose "Startup Repair" this time. Wait until the process is completed.

If Windows is successfully repaired, you are done. If it is not, you will have to reinstall Windows with a Windows Installation CD.

Comment: Boot Repair didn't do anything. bootrec /fixmbr worked, but grub is now gone - no ubuntu. I wanted to dual boot, as I used to be able to do earlier.